# Is it possible to wrap elements inside head

Tags: javascript, html, dom, head

For silently changing pages via dom manipulation, I figured it might be helpful to wrap certain related child elements of the head together, but I don't find any element type that would do that.

Injecting and removing the single elements doesn't feel right and replacing the entire head content leads to a short glitch at least in my firefox and chrome, possibly because the css is missing for a short moment.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <thingy class="generalStuff">
    <meta name="viewport" content="..." />
    <script src="..."></script>
  </thingy>
  <thingy class="forThisPage">
    <script src="..."></script>
    <script src="..."></script>
  </thingy>
</head>

<body>
  ...
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what's your end game?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: That's invalid HTML, which could cause many problems.

Comment: You sound a bit [Reacty](https://reactjs.org/) to me.

Comment: To my understanding you can't make DOM manipulations to things in the head section. Are you using any server side technology on this site to make these changes before the HTML is processed and delivered to the client?

Comment: @DanielA.White @j08691 I thought it was too much to describe the whole thing from the beginning. Basically I'm building a website where whenever an internal link is clicked, javascript loads the requested page and replaces the contents of `head`and `main`and pushes the url to the history

Comment: @tshimkus it does work, for example appending scripts or changing the title. And some pages will be assembled by the server and some are static. So that's why I'm searching for a universal way

Comment: use framework instead it may help you when you need a particular script or head contents you can define your own in block head or block content as in case of django templating and in case of laravel too using @section('head') and extending the base html will work out